# SharePoint 2010: cannot create calculated site column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

I am trying to create a calculated site column in SharePoint 2010 but as soon as I click on radio button of "calculated (calculation based on other column)" I get an error.
I am following these steps.

1. Go to "Site Settings"
2. Click "Site Columns"
3. Click "Create"
4. Write "MyTestColumn" in "column name"
5. Select "calculated (calculation based on other column)" option

This is where I got an error. Below, I have mentioned error from log file. please note that I didn't press OK button. As soon as I select calculated option I get this error. also below error says that key "`'Title_Title'`" already added but trust me I didn't write this (`'Title_Title'`) in any column name.

Error is:

> 09/15/2017 17:08:45.02    w3wp.exe (0x2574)   0x360C  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'Title_Title'  Key being added: 'Title_Title'
>       at System.Collections.SortedList.Add(Object key, Object value) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.BasicFieldEditPage.WriteFieldNamesForFormulaColumnPicker(TextWriter output, SPFieldCollection fields, String currentDisplayName) 
>       at ASP._layouts_fldnew_aspx.__Render__control15(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
>       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
>       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) 
>       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
>       at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
>       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   725f06d5-390f-486b-9c20-1424cba5feec

Comment: see answer posted on below post. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225861/cannot-create-site-column-of-calculated-type/226096#226096